# Extending the Release Burn Down Chat to restrict to a Story Hierarchy

Tags: rally

Very fond of the release burn down chart, but as we have features from different areas in a single release I am looking to get a Burn Down Chart scoped to a specific top level story. In this case the only stories to be considered would be its leaf stories that are scheduled for the release in question.

Does anyone have an idea if this is possible or where to start? I found the code here: https://github.com/RallyApps/app-catalog/tree/master/src/apps/charts/burndown but couldn't see how to restrict the scope of the work products being considered.

Other ways I tried to get this view:
- I tried a custom view on the main user-stories view filtered to a release, but the summary rows give you a summary for all the stories in that tree, not just those which it filtered to
- Track work product status view only does story count whereas I need the total story points from the stories (not tasks) to be reported on

If anyone knows anywhere else I can get a nice view of a story hierarchy progress, scoped to a release that would also be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

As a starting point, the app accesses historical data via Lookback API. Documentation for it is available [here](https://rally1.rallydev.com/analytics/doc).
The example below is from "Work item hierarchy" section of that document:

> To retrieve all Stories that descend from Story 333 (includes 333,
>   444, 555, 666, 888, and 999 but not Defect 777), you would include
>   this clause in your query:
>
> {
>
> _ItemHierarchy: 333,
>
> _TypeHierarchy: “HierarchicalRequirement”
>
> }

BurnDownChart.js from the [repo](https://github.com/RallyApps/app-catalog/blob/master/src/apps/charts/burndown/BurnDownChart.js) has a store of type "Rally.data.lookback.SnapshotStore", which you may filter using work item hierarchy.

AppSDK2 [SnapshotStore](https://help.rallydev.com/apps/2.0rc1/doc/#!/api/Rally.data.lookback.SnapshotStore)  accesses data from Lookback API.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the pointers. I'm really struggling through the documentation to come up with html for the custom html app that will extend the Rally.apps.charts.burndown.BurnDownChart and allow me to add some attributes to the SnapshotStore config. Is this possible or is it more a case of defining an entirely new app? Thanks again, Andy